# Can''t call commit when autocommit=true

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jhipster, mssql-jdbc

Hi I am using jhipster generated code with dependecies of 3.0.7. I am trying to use custom encryption and decryption of the database password using the code below. The decryption is successful as I debugged, however in the native server session, I could see the auto commit is set to true which is the cause of the error. The default auto commit Pasted the error below. It looks like the hikari auto commit is not set or something. This has got nothing to do with mysql. There is a class called NativeServerSession in com.mysql.cj.protocol.a which sets the auto commit as true that causes the error. i tried giving auto commit true as well in the yml file. But I get the same error. Please help. If I remove the encryption and remove the databaseconfiguration class, it works and the NativeServerSession auto commit is set as true as well.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.my.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class DatabaseConfiguration extends DriverManagerDataSource implements InitializingBean  {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        this.decryptPass();
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    public void decryptPass() {
        String retrievedPassword = this.getPassword();
        ..decrpt code goes here
        this.setPassword(decryptedDBPassword);          
    }
}
```

Application.yml

```
datasource:
    #driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    default-auto-commit: false
    auto-commit: false
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&relaxAutoCommit=true
    username: dbusername
    password: encryptedpassword
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
      default-auto-commit: false
    tomcat:
      default-auto-commit: false
    data-source-properties:
      cachePrepStmts: true
      prepStmtCacheSize: 250
      prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
      useServerPrepStmts: true
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    database: MYSQL
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
      hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
      hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
      hibernate.cache.hazelcast.instance_name: microservice
      hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts: true
      hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_lite_member: true
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC C
onnection
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:352)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:254)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:537)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:534)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:305)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
        at com.dxc.ica.safetravel.web.rest.AccommodationResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$19aa9477.getAccommodationTypes(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at com.dxc.ica.safetravel.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:38)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionC
oordinatorImpl.java:272)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:533)
        ... 120 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can''t call commit when autocommit=true
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:67)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:81)
        ... 123 common frames omitted

2020-08-02 17:01:28.853  WARN 12984 --- [ XNIO-13 task-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to commit a
gainst JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it helps anyone, i changed the below property to false. I just cant figure out how it works with value true when the encryption is not there.

```
properties:
  hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: false
```

Comment: Thank you, in my case the problem was from:

jpa:
    properties:
        connection:
          provider_disables_autocommit: true